# Which codepage is this

Tags: url, query-string

im sending this query string

> param=Declaração de Carência

and getting "Declaraï¿½ï¿½o de Carï¿½ncia" as result of Request.QueryString["param"]

can anyone help me pls? ive tryed every overload of encoding...

Comment: Are you sending these url encoded? Accented characters have no place in urls yet.

Comment: Yes i am encoding them... if i dont encode it the result is "DeclaraÃ§Ã£o de CarÃªncia"

Comment: That is at least moderately correct though. `>>> print u'DeclaraÃ§Ã£o de CarÃªncia'.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')`
`Declaração de Carência`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your framework has misdecoded it, damaging it irreversably.

```
>>> print u'Declaraï¿½ï¿½o de Carï¿½ncia'.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
Declara��o de Car�ncia
```

Seek further help about the specific framework you are using.

Comment: thank you... i'll... i ranked your answer... if i confirm this ill mark as answer

Comment: verified! thanks... its disapointing but tks... specially because its the .net framework...